# How to format Jquery Jtable date field edit problem?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, hibernate, jquery-jtable

I have a jtable jquery where  I get the date from javahibernate  pojo change to json and it gets auto change to this format Apr 7, 2020 12:00:00 AM.
    In my jtable the display format for the field is  set to 'dd-MMM-yyyy' I get the following error:

> jTable WARNING: Given date is not properly formatted: Apr 7, 2020
>   12:00:00 AM

This only happens when the field type is date

```
 start_date: {
                 title: 'Date',
                 type: 'date',
                 displayFormat:'dd-MMM-yyyy',
                 list: true,
                 width: '8%'
                }
```

Can anyone help me to get the formatting fixed? I tried the same in pojo but it's not working.

Comment: You can add a custom `display` function and format explicitly as expected. Refer: http://jtable.org/ApiReference/FieldOptions#fopt-dependsOn

Comment: Bt what it will do in case of create? I mean edit and create display will be Different.  How do I handle that?

Comment: If you can share a minimal 'reproducible' (with hardcoded json) version of the code, that will help to get the complete picture right.

Answer (score 0):

Use moment jquery library.
This is what I have done to change the date format.

```
       date: {
            title: 'Date',
            display: function(data) {
                return moment(data.record.timestamp).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            },
        },
```